# Search Filter CPT, Custom Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a custom loop to display projects in a grid on my Wordpress site. I'm creating filters for these projects and am getting stuck on the input search. I am getting a 400 error on my admin-ajax.php and not sure how to get this working. Can someone give me any tips? Here is my code:

**PHP code for loop in functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
    ); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

    ?>


    <div class="projects-column">
    <div class="project-image">
    <?php $image = get_field('image');
    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="project-image-tester" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="project-info">
    <span class="proj-name" style="font-weight: bold;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></span>
    </div>


    <div class="project-onhover">
    <span class="proj-title"><p><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></p></span>
    <span class="proj-details">
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">LOCATION: </span><?php the_field('location'); ?></p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">PROJECT VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">SERVICES: </span> <?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'project_services', '', ', ', '' ) ); ?> </p></span>
    </div><!--projects-on-hover-tester -->
    </div><!--project-image-->
    </div><!--projects-column -->


    <?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    php endif;
    die();
}
```

**JS code also in functions.php**

```
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#projects-container').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}
```

I localized the script earlier for another ajax request, so this is where the url is coming from:

```
wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wpAjax',
    array('ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used incorrect names for the hook. [As documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#ajax-action), the hook name should be `wp_ajax_` followed by the `action` parameter that you're sending in the request. In your example that's `data_fetch`, so:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','data_fetch');
```

Should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_data_fetch', 'data_fetch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch' );
```

Comment: Thank you, overlooked that one. That has fixed the no results issue, but it's still not returning back filtered results based on what is being searched. I don't think the "keyword" coding is working to filter by the project titles. Could you point me in the right direction to get that working? Thank you thank you thank you again!!!